# How to show the modal dialog based on label type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to show a open modal dialog based on the label click, but it is showing the same(`All Recommendations`) modal dialog even if i clicked on other label`(Entities By type)` . How to handle this , please help me thanks in advance

```
const ExportTypes: Array<{ label: string; id: string }> = [
 { label: 'All Recommendations', id: 'AllRecommendations' },
 { label: 'Entities By type', id: 'EntitiesBytype' },  
];

const handleModalExport = useCallback(
() => {
  if (ExportTypes.some(e => e.id === 'AllRecommendations')) {
      openModalDialog({
        title: t('Export all recommendations'),
        renderContent: () => <RecommendationExportModel />,
      });
    }
   else if(ExportTypes.some(e => e.id === 'EntitiesBytype')) { 
      openModalDialog({
        title: t('Export all'),
        renderContent: () => <RecommendationExportEntitiesModel />,
      });
    }
  },
 [openModalDialog, t],
);

{ExportTypes.map((objType) => (
  <MenuItem key={objType.id} onClick={handleModalExport}>
     {t(objType.label)}
  </MenuItem>
))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The **some()** method tests whether *at least one element in the array passes the test* implemented by the provided function. It returns true if, in the array, it finds an element for which the provided function returns true; otherwise it returns false. It doesn't modify the array.

In this case, when you run `handleModalExport()`, it's checking your `ExportTypes` constant for if it has an item with an `id` equal to `AllRecommendations`. Since it always has that, anytime you click the `MenuItem`, it will always pass the first conditional since that item id is always present in your constant.

You're basically not using the clicked item's id which is the problem. Your `MenuItem` needs to pass in the `id` that you are clicking and that you want to do a check on.

Try using this instead:

```
<MenuItem key={objType.id} onClick={() => handleModalExport(objType.id})}>
```

Then update your callback to use this dynamic `id` from your onClick event:

```
const handleModalExport = useCallback(
(id) => {
  switch (id) {
    case 'AllRecommendations':
      openModalDialog({
          title: t('Export all recommendations'),
          renderContent: () => <RecommendationExportModel />,
        });
      }
    break;
    case 'EntitiesBytype':
      openModalDialog({
        title: t('Export all'),
        renderContent: () => <RecommendationExportEntitiesModel />,
      });
    break;
    default:
      // handle this, throw? do nothing?
  },
 [openModalDialog, t],
);
```